# Zxing.net set module size for data matrix

Tags: c#, zxing

I need to set the module size for a datamatrix generated with zxing.net. I couldn't find something in the code with a quick look.
Also I tried it with scaling the width and height, but since the size can vary based on the input data that doesn't work out..
Does anyone know a way to do that?